# Combobox filtered by column value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a combobox in my userform which needs to be populated by only the members of the contracts department in a list of users in a table

I've had a look around and can only find ways to do this referencing a worksheet, not a table so I've had a go at knocking something up below but I think I'm still a way off, any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub VariationRequest_Initialize()
Dim LstRw As Long
LstRw = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("Setup").Range("Users").Columns(1))

for i = 0 to LstRw
if Users.cells(i, 2).value = "Contracts" then
    User.AddItem(Users.cells(i, 1).value)
end if
next i

end sub
```

Comment: A table object is referenced via `Worksheet.ListObject([index or name])`

Comment: so just change .Range to .ListObject?

Comment: @Mistella, I have tried your fix, unfortunately it gives me error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method" on that line that wasn't previously there.  The error I was previously getting wasn't until the line starting "if Users.cells" which was Error 424 "Object Required".

Comment: I'm not sure how it works with a Named range, but if you `Dim tbl as ListObject` then `Set tbl = Worksheet.ListObject(1)` (_Assuming the table is the only list object for that worksheet_), you should be able to use attributes such as `tbl.DataBodyRange` or `tbl.HeaderRange`. (_I can't remember if there's a basic `tbl.Range`_) You should be able to use the _Table Range_ objects similar to how you would use range for a worksheet or other range-object. **Note:** I think if you use `.DataBodyRange.Cells(1,1)` it would reference the first cell in that range - not the first cell in the sheet.

Comment: Also, my comment about referencing tables wasn't a fix, so much as an informational note, so you had to terms to use when searching for table-referencing information. (_Since you had mentioned not being able to find any info_)

Comment: If "Users" is the name of your table, that would be helpful information to include in your question. I had assumed you were working with a named-range.